# How do I check if the app is running or not from a background service?

Tags: flutter, dart, process, background, dart-isolates

What I'm trying to achieve is that a background task is able to check whether the flutter app (the main isolate) is active/running or not, and then based on that, perform some task.

How can I make that check?